# The result of a delegate init call must be immediately returned or assigned to 'self'

Tags: objective-c, object, self

In my project I have a class that declares following methods:

```
-(id)initWithSections:(NSUInteger)s rows:(NSUInteger)r
{
        if(self=[self init])
        {sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:s];

            for (int i=0; i<=s; i++){
                NSMutableArray *rows = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:r];
                for (int j=0; j<=r; j++){
                    [rows insertObject:[NSNull null] atIndex:j];
                }
                [sections addObject:rows];
            }
        }

    return self;
}
```

I also one more method that calls the method above:

```
-(id)OneMoreMethod:(NSMutableArray *)obj1 :(NSMutableArray *)obj2
{
    NSInteger b = 3;

   [self initWithSections:b rows:b];//The result of a delegate init call must be immediately returned or assigned to 'self'

    return  self;
}
```

I got error:

> The result of a delegate init call must be immediately returned or assigned to 'self'.

I don't see an error. The most interesting this is build success in other project.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `[self init...]` from a non-init method.

Comment: Change the return value "id" to "instancetype". And you haven't turned on anywhere near enough warnings in your code, so expect totally avoidable bugs that will cost you many hours to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since initWithSections:rows: returns "self", it's asking from you to use that self. You're just ignoring the "self" returned from that method.

It doesn't look good, and also it will probably cause another problems, but this will solve the original problem:

```
self = [self initWithSections:b rows:b];

return self;
```

Comment: Of course you know have a method that must be called as [[SomeClass alloc] OneMoreMethod:...]. It seems someone doesn't quite understand init methods.

Comment: @gnasher729 Indeed. Someone is having (minor) problems with OOP, first of all.